# SAP doc about configuration RFC user

Tags: abap, saprfc

I am writing docs for our product [modlink](https://www.tbz-pariv.de/produkte/modlink/modlink-intro) and I would like to add an URL to docs from SAP.

I would like to link to the docs where the configuration of a RFC-user gets explained. If I use my favorite search engine, then I find a lot of stuff, but nothing looks like a reliable link to SAP docs.

Could someone please provide me an URL where I can find authoritative docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this SAP Note as a place to start:

[338537 - RFC user authorizations for data exchange R/3 backend <-> CRM](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0338537)

It contains detailed instructions how to create communications users and explains some security aspects. Also simplified guide can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6f42ecd66c4b10149b80ebae9754201e/7.01.20/en-US/f4d228382a214ce4ae9ede2096003e7f.html).

Note that authorizations `SAP_ALL`/`SAP_NEW` specified in simplified guide are excessive and are relevant only for this CRM case. Usually `S_RFC` authorization [is quite sufficient](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73/7.3.16/en-US/48/95128d94cc73eae10000000a42189b/frameset.htm) (also `S_RFCACL` for trusted RFC connections).

Comment: SAP_ALL / SAP_NEW authorizations are not only excessive, but such authorizations on production system will trigger a *lot* of questions from auditing / security team.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, dunno why SAP put them into the guide :)

Comment: The sap Note 338537 needs a password. I have one, but the need to login is .... I don't know how to call it. How would you call it?

Comment: `The sap Note 338537 needs a password` any SAP note needs S-user :) I downloaded PDF-copy for you [here](https://file.io/toYgDS)

Comment: @Suncatcher This solves the closed-docs issue for this particular question. How could this be solved for the future? How to suggest this feature request (open docs) to SAP?

Comment: what do you mean by open docs? prevent SAP notes from requiring password?

Answer (score 1):

This note explains the *minimal* authorizations that an RFC user needs to have: 460089